# Line up text based on line contents

Tags: shell, posix, text-formatting

Is it possible to insert new lines in order to line up the contents of a file?

I have:

```
1:1   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur    1:1   This is sample text of varying length.
      adipiscing elit.                          1:2   This is another paragraph in this file.
1:2   Vivamus integer non suscipit taciti mus         Yet another sentence in this paragraph.
      etiam at primis tempor sagittis.          1:3   Another paragraph can be found here!
```

How can I add spaces appropriately so that the numbers line up?

Expected output:

```
1:1   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur          This is sample text of varying length.
      adipiscing elit.                          
1:2   Vivamus integer non suscipit taciti mus         This is another paragraph in this file.    
      etiam at primis tempor sagittis.                Yet another sentence in this paragraph.
1:3                                                   Another paragraph can be found here!
```

Edit: since the lines would be lined up, there is no need for the numbers to be repeated so they can be removed.

POSIX compliance is preferred.

Comment: Is there any particular logic where `1:2 This...` needs to be broken out of it's current line and appended to the next line? Same for 'Another paragraph...` being added to it's on unique line. We'll need the rules in order to create a script.

Comment: @doneal24 It seems it's the paragraph labels, `1:1`, `1:2` etc., that should be aligned on the same lines in the left and right column of text. So we would need to come up with a way to parse the left and right columns more or less separately, and then align them for output based on the labels.

Comment: Yeah it's the paragraph labels. Essentially corresponding lines should be aligned

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm not sure this is really defined. Should `...1:3 Another paragraph` be translated to `^1:3 Another paragraph`? How do you handle the second #:# tag when it has not been previously used?

Comment: Just chiming in here, you could use something like awk to check if fields x and y (the numbers) are equal to each other. For 1:3, field x would be empty since we're not defining a third paragraph on the left. You could detect this and add an empty line there (with 1:3 moved to the start of the line). This should also work if the right column is missing a field but instead add the blank space there.

Comment: @Venem Can you edit your question to confirm that `1:3` should be moved to the start of the line?

Comment: On second thoughts, this does seem slightly too complicated to do to be viable. The script would have to execute quickly enough for a user not to notice. It is possible to go through the whole file and add the spaces in but considering the sheer amount of text this would have to go through, the script would be insanely slow. I thought there was some nifty little-known tool built in to UNIX that would easily solve this but that doesn't seem the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU `awk` to read the text as a fixed-width set of records, where each record is divided into fields of widths 6 (left label), 42 (left line of text), 6 (right label), and 42 (right line of text):

```c
BEGIN {
        FIELDWIDTHS = "6 42 6 42"
}

# New label seen on the left hand side.
# If this is a completely new label, then
# add it to the end of the "labels" array.
$1 != "      " {
        llabel = $1
        if (!seenlabels[llabel]++)
                labels[++n] = llabel
}

# Same as above, but for the right hand side.
$3 != "      " {
        rlabel = $3
        if (!seenlabels[rlabel]++)
                labels[++n] = rlabel
}

# Add text to the labelled paragraphs, left and right,
# as strings delimited by ORS (newline).
{
        ltext[llabel] = (ltext[llabel] == "" ? $2 : ltext[llabel] ORS $2)
        rtext[rlabel] = (rtext[rlabel] == "" ? $4 : rtext[rlabel] ORS $4)
}

# At end, output.
END {
        # Iterate over all paragraphs (there are "n" of them).
        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
                delete llines
                delete rlines

                # Split the text for the left and right paragraph,
                # into arrays, "llines" and "rlines".
                a = split(ltext[labels[i]], llines, ORS)
                b = split(rtext[labels[i]], rlines, ORS)

                # The arrays may be of different lengths, but
                # "c" will be the length of the longest, i.e.
                # the number of lines of the paragraph to the
                # left or right, whichever is longes.
                c = (a > b ? a : b)

                # Print the first line of the left and right
                # of this paragarph (includes the label at the left).
                printf("%-6s%-42s%-6s%-42s\n", labels[i], llines[1], "", rlines[1])

                # Then print the other lines (no label).
                for (j = 2; j <= c; ++j)
                        printf("%-6s%-42s%-6s%-42s\n", "", llines[j], "", rlines[j])
        }
}
```

Testing:

```bash
$ cat file
1:1   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur    1:1   This is sample text of varying length.
      adipiscing elit.                          1:2   This is another paragraph in this file.
1:2   Vivamus integer non suscipit taciti mus         Yet another sentence in this paragraph.
      etiam at primis tempor sagittis.          1:3   Another paragraph can be found here!
```

```bash
$ gawk -f script file
1:1   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur          This is sample text of varying length.
      adipiscing elit.
1:2   Vivamus integer non suscipit taciti mus         This is another paragraph in this file.
      etiam at primis tempor sagittis.                Yet another sentence in this paragraph.
1:3                                                   Another paragraph can be found here!
```

Since this is using GNU-specific extensions to the POSIX specification of `awk` (the `FIELDWIDTHS` variable), it is not a strictly POSIX answer.

For a POSIX compliant answer just replace the `BEGIN` section with:

```
{
    rec = $0
    $0 = ""
    $1 = substr(rec,1,6)
    $2 = substr(rec,7,42)
    $3 = substr(rec,49,6)
    $4 = substr(rec,55)
}
```